# Unsubscribe to Resubscribe - DE Manager

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

We are using DEmanager for the form and that form is linked to the data extension. Right now everything is working smoothly. 
But when someone receives an email and then they unsubscribe from our communication, they get unsubscribed. Which is completely how it should work. But when they re-fill out the form the publication list doesn't get updated. Their "Status" remains "unsubscribed" even thou they just subscribed.

Can you please help me out with this situation ASAP!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

As you're finding, DE Manager simply add/updates records in your Data Extension. It does nothing to with List Subscriptions. You have a few options. Here's a non-exhaustive list:

1. Change to using [WebCollect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_studio_web_collect.htm&type=5), rather than using [DEManager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_demanager.htm&type=5). The two interfaces are very similar. Web Collect adds/updates records in Lists, rather than Data Extensions. Including the "Status" field in your form data, along with the ID of your All Subscribers list has the effect of resubscribing, if currently unsubscribed:

   http://cl.s7.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?lid=178&Email%20Address=foo@bar.com&Status=Active&mid=123456&SubAction=sub_add_update
2. Add a hidden datestamp field to your DEManager form and schedule an Automation that selects recently updated records in your Data Extension and inserts them into a staging table containing three fields; "Subscriber Key", "Email Address" and "Status" (Active). Extract out the staging data to flat file, transfer to the Import directory and then import into the All Subscribers list.
3. Do similar to option 2, but substitute the extract/transfer/import tasks with an SSJS Activity task that iterates through newly updated records and updates All Subscribers directly by API (not recommended).
4. Use server-side scripting, rather than DEManager, to manipulate your Data Extension record and subscribe/resubscribe behaviour. See the [DataEvents Route](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/putDataExtensionRowByKey.htm) (REST), [Managing Data In Data Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/managing_data_in_data_extensions.htm) (SOAP) and [Updating a Subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updating_an_existing_subscriber_using_the_create_method_with_updateadd.htm) (SOAP)